# How to generate a random number or string every time terraform runs

Tags: terraform

I am trying to generate a random number with terraform every time terraform runs. The random_integer resource will generate a random number 1st time it runs but then it retains the same number. Any way to change this behaviour and get a unique value every time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A sketch of a hacky solution:

- use [Terraform Random provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs)
- with `keepers` set to [current timestamp](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/timestamp.html)

---

I've just tested this code:

```
resource "random_id" "rng" {
  keepers = {
    first = "${timestamp()}"
  }     
  byte_length = 8
}
```

and then I can refer to:

```
random_id.rng.hex
```

and it gives different values every time

Comment: `timestamp` would return a different value for each execution, which would trigger a new random output though. `keepers` Map needs to have a constant value in this scenario.

Comment: @MattSchuchard OP wants a different value for each execution. Not sure what a constant value they supposedly want. (BTW, I've edited my answer to give a more complete example).

Comment: Good call; I read the sentence about wanting the same value each time and thought that was the desired behavior, and not the next sentence when stating the opposite.

Comment: Can it be `"first = timestamp()`, or it must be `first = "${timestamp()}"`?

Comment: first = timestamp() didn't work for me, while first = "${timestamp()}" gave a deprecation warning, but it was working as expected.